# how to undo sqlplus that created a lower case table name

Tags: sql, oracle

it is amazing! how soo much fail can happen to an awesome exe XD

how to create this error:

```
cd "c:\new folder\"
sqlplus ABC/abc@10.0.10.12:1530/ALPHABET
@somefile.sql
;
commit;
exit
```

inside the somefile.sql:

```
 CREATE TABLE "ABC"."ALL_NORMALIDS_sqlldr" 
 (  
 "OID" NUMBER(6,0), 
 "NODE" VARCHAR2(50), 
 "TRANSTYPE" VARCHAR2(30), 
 "CREATED" DATE, 
 "UPDATED" DATE)
```

the result is

```
 Table Created.
```

Afterwards after trying to insert stuff into the table, noticed i couldnt even select it (in sqlplus or sqldeveloper)

tried all sorts of:

```
select * from ALL_NORMALIDS_sqlldr;
seoect * from ALL_NORMALIDS_SQLLDR;

 ERROR at line 1:
 ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

but it did apear inside the table list of sqldeveloper :)
also found it with :

```
 select *
 from all_objects
 where object_type in ('TABLE','VIEW')
 and object_name = 'ALL_NORMALIDS_sqlldr'
```

could not be deleted, could not be overwritten (by previous create table statement)

anywho 
found solution later:

tables can contain lower case letters!!!
but they need to be quoted!!!

```
 select * from "ALL_NORMALIDS_sqlldr"
```

works!!!

```
 -- i decided to open the case for others who faced something like this :)
 -- have a nice day!
```

Comment: This is pretty standard behavior in Oracle. Since you created the table using double quotes `""`, you need to now use the quotes in your SELECT statement. Ditto for columns as well.

Comment: This is how the SQL standard requires quoted identifiers to work and is well documented in the Oracle manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements008.htm#i27561

Answer (score 1):

A simple rename command should do the trick. This is tested on Oracle 10G version. Should work in all versions upwards of Oracle 10G.

```
rename "ALL_NORMALIDS_sqlldr" to ALL_NORMALIDS_SQLLDR
```